# Nighttime Sensor Command

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found a small cave in MCPE in a desert that I thought would be easy to turn into a house, so I did. However, unfortunately, I underestimated how good the light-source would be - I made two separate redstone lamps, one with a normal daylight sensor on top, and one with an inverted sensor. But the only difference between the two is that the inverted one keeps the light on day and night. Is there any command to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Where are these lamps?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this before and I think that your best bet would be to use a normal sensor and invert the signal with a redstone torch. That seems to be the only way to get it to work.
[image]